# High DPI aware taskpane (or ActiveX control) in Excel 2016!? How?

Tags: excel, activex, dpi, excel-2016

We're changing our application to support HDPI on a per monitor basis, as the latest versions of Microsoft Excel 2016 support.

We can scale our own dialog boxes, and get notifications when the DPI of our windows change, but the ActiveX control we use when calling ICTPFactory.CreateCTP is always created with 96 dpi and only SystemAware DPI awareness. If I use GetDpiForWindow & GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext on the parent windows, I can see the parent window of our window (CMMOcxHost) is 96dpi/SystemAware, but the CMMOcxHostChildWindowMixedMode window and it's parents are all 144dpi/MonitorAware.

The following image shows the windows from Spy++ (see below). The windows below the red line are all created as SystemAware (no doubt by changing the thread DPI awareness), but the windows above are all monitor aware. I want the CMMOcxHost to be MonitorAware so we can then drawn our window in high resolution.

[DPI awareness for window and parents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP5H1.png)

Is there a registry setting that tells Office that our taskpane ActiveX control is HDPI aware? The DLL hosting our ActiveX control has a manifest indicating support for Windows 10 and true so I assume the Office taskpane is not using that to determine DPI awareness?

Can a member from the Excel/Office developer team advise please?

Comment: If you insist on an answer from an Office dev then just wait for your MSDN forum question to get answered.  Might take a while, google "office add-in dpiaware" to keep you busy.  Lots of hits, several existing SO questions about it.

Comment: I don't mind who replies Hans, but having spent a week stepping through Excel to try identify when/where the thread DPI awareness is been changed before the ActiveX control creation, and going through all the Google/Bing hits (which are not the same issue BTW), I want to avoid answers like just call SetProcessDpiAwareness/SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext  etc.. which will not work. I'd just like to get to an answer without it getting drown out in non-answers.